# $\exists\,\, lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \iff \exists \,\,lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)+c$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, functions

Consider a function $f(x): A \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and another one $g(x)=f(x)+c$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x_0$ be a limit point for $A$. Is it the following true?

$$\exists \,\,\,\,\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \iff \exists \,\,\,\,\lim_{x \to x_0}g(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can hit this with the epsilon-delta hammer pretty easily. Assume that the initial limit exists; that is $\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists\delta >0$ s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Now let $\epsilon>0$, and we want to show that $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|g(x)-L'|<\epsilon$. But just make $L'=L+c$, and we end up with needing a $\delta$ that makes $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)+c-L-c|<\epsilon$, which we already have.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Let $L\in \mathbb R$,
$$\forall \eta>0 \;\;\forall x\in(x_0-\eta,x_0+\eta)\setminus\{x_0\}$$

$$\;\;|g(x)-L|=|f(x)-L|$$